# Making a return inside callback

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, callback

```
public static string GetFoo() {

        string source = GameInfoUtil.GetSource(repairRequest, () => {
            return "0"; // this line gives error
        });
        .
        .
        MORE WORK, BUT WANT TO SKIP IT
    }


public static string GetSource(WebRequest request, Action failureCallback) {
        // DOING WORK HERE WITH REQUEST
        if(WORK IS SUCCESSFULL) RETURN CORRECT STRING ELSE CALL ->
        failureCallback();
        return "";
    }
```

I want to do smthing like this, but it gives me error:

```
Error   2   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Action' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.
Error   1   Since 'System.Action' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression   C:\Users\Jaanus\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Bot\Bot\Utils\GameInfoUtil.cs 58  5   Bot
```

What I want to do, is when something happens in `GameInfoUtil.GetSource`, it will call out my delegate, and the `GetFoo` method will return and not continue work.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a callback rather than normal exception handling? This all seems rather complicated - which is particularly troublesome if you're not entirely comfortable with callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Action` delegate returns void. You are trying to return the string "0".

If you change `Action` to `Func<string>` and return that value.

```
public static string GetSource(WebRequest request, Func<string> failureCallback) {
    // DOING WORK HERE WITH REQUEST
    if(!(WORK IS SUCCESSFULL))
    {
        return failureCallback();
    }
    return "";
}
```

your code will work.

The code within the lambda can't return from the outer function. Internally the lambda is converted to a regular method (with an unspeakable name).

```
public static string GetFoo() {
    string source = GameInfoUtil.GetSource(repairRequest, () => {
        return "0"; // this line gives error
    });
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public static string GetFoo() {
    string source = GameInfoUtil.GetSource(repairRequest, XXXYYYZZZ);
}

public static string XXXYYYZZZ()
{
    return "0";
}
```

now you can easily understand why `return "0"` can't return from GetFoo.

Comment: Doesnt `return failureCallback();` equal to `return return "0"` ? If lambda can't  return from outer function, is there a way to do it someway else?

Comment: It is equivalent to `return (()=>return "0";)();`. You should return a status class with a `bool success` and a `string errorValue` property and inspect the `success` property in the GetFoo method.

Comment: Yeah that would be a solution for any other programming language, I thought csharp had some cool possibility to do what I needed with callbacks.

Answer (score 5):

An `Action` delegate should return void. You cannot return a string. You can change it to `Func<string>`:

```
string source = GameInfoUtil.GetSource(repairRequest, () => {
        return "0";
    });

public static string GetSource(WebRequest request, Func<string> failureCallback)
{
    if( <some condition> )
        return failureCallback(); // return the return value of callback
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Will the `GetFoo` return "0" then or the `GetSource` will return "0"? I need to return from `GetFoo` but from inside `GetSource`.

Comment: @Jaanus no, it will `return "";` after calling `failureCallback();`. Use next code `if(...) return failureCallback(); else return "";`

Comment: I need to call the `return` of `GetFoo` from inside `GetSource`, does your solution do this, or your solution only makes `string source == "0"` ?

Comment: @Jaanus That's not possible. You can't do that in any programming language. You can never control the flow of a function from *another* fucntion, *without passing some messages*.