# A Method which return a value cannot be passed to exception handler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, mvp

I'm handling exceptions centrally in a method (`ExecuteAction(Action action)`). I have a problem when passing action to this method when it returns a value.

In following code I'm getting this error:

`Since 'System.Action' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression`

How to solve this problem?

```
public decimal CalculateInstalment(decimal amount, int months)
{
    this.ExecutAction(() =>
    {
        var result = amount / months;
        return Math.Round(result, 2);
    });
}

protected bool ExecutAction(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
        return true;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); return false; ; }
    catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); return false; }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); return false; }
    catch (System.Exception e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); return false; };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447218/making-a-return-inside-callback).

Comment: What do you want to do with the value of result?

Comment: `Action` has no return type (Void).  If you want to return a value (like `Math.Round(result, 2)`) then you need to use [`Func<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You should never catch `NullReferenceException`. It almost always indicates a programming error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, Action types do not return a value, but you can refer to outer variables.  If you're trying to get the value, consider a setup like this:

```
public decimal CalculateInstalment(decimal amount, int months)
{
    var result = 0.0;
    this.ExecutAction(() =>
    {
        result = Math.Round((amount / months), 2);
    });

    return result;
}

protected bool ExecutAction(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
        return true;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); return false; ; }
    catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); return false; }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); return false; }
    catch (System.Exception e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); return false; };
}
```

Comment: If this is a centralized way to handle exceptions, and is going to be called from several places, this is going to be a pain in the butt and imposes a big restrictions on what kind of delegates can be called. You most definitely need an overload that properly handles `Func<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are Returning a value in

```
this.ExecutAction(() =>
{
    var result = amount / months;
    return Math.Round(result, 2);
    });
}
```

Actions don't return values. They always "return void" so to speak.

You need to change to:

```
protected bool ExecutAction(Func<object> fn)
```

BTW, this is really "smelly" to me... Here is a sample I guess?

```
protected T Execute<T>(Func<T> fn) {
  try {
    return fn();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    // do whatever
    // return null and check for it. null checking uuuuuggghhhhh
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to change the argument to a `Func` you should make `ExecuteAction` generic in the return type. Then you have to change the return type of `ExecuteAction` from `bool` for this to work.

Comment: I agree. But I would never write this in the first place.

Comment: This won't work anyhow. Returning inside of a delegate only returns from the delegate, not the containing method. The final return statement must come from the method.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bool ExecutAction(Action action)` to execute a delegate that returns a value doesn't make much sense - how do you expect to retrieve the value from that delegate?

In addition to your `ExecuteAction` method, you should use the `TryXXX` pattern (as seen in the various `TryParse` methods in the BCL) for delegates that return values:

```
protected T TryExecutAction<T>(Func<T> func, out bool success)
{
    try
    {
        T temp = func();
        success = true;
        return temp;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e);  }
    catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e);  }
    catch (System.Exception e) { _MessageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); };

    success = false;
    return default(T);
}
```

Don't forget to return the value back to the caller:

```
public decimal CalculateInstalment(decimal amount, int months)
{
    bool success;

    return this.TryExecutAction(() =>
    {
        var result = amount / months;
        return Math.Round(result, 2);
    }, out success);
}
```